# Unable to connect to ejabberd localhost

Tags: xmpp, ubuntu-12.04, ejabberd, smack

I am tyring to connect to the ejabberd localhost from my android application The ejabbered server does not show the online user on ejabberd web admin.

```
    AbstractXMPPConnection conn1;
    conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection("MyID@localhost", "password", "192.168.1.23");

        conn1.connect();
        if(conn1.isConnected())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"conn 1 successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }



   // Create a connection to the jabber.org server on a specific port.
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setUsernameAndPassword("MyId@localhost", "password")
            .setServiceName("jabber.org")
            .setHost("192.1**.1.2*")//My Ip address
            .setPort(5222)
            .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
            .build();

    AbstractXMPPConnection conn2 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

        conn2.connect();
        if(conn2.isConnected())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"conn2 successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems incorrect:

- Username should be the username without XMPP domain (Just MyId).
- ServiceName is set to "jabber.org", which mean you will try to connect to that server, not your local server.

Comment: if 192.168.1.24:5280/admin is the domain then what should i write in setHost and setService ??

Comment: It depends on the XMPP domain you configured for service. Host may be your IP address.

Comment: my domain is somewhat 192.168,***.2*:5280/admin ....but the real issue is that the following code isn't giving any sort of exception ....if there have been an exception i would have figured it out somehow...any solution for this :/