# Unable to connect to eJabberd server using strophe

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I have setup an eJabberd server on my local machine.
When i enter the below url in the browser:

```
http://localhost:5280/admin
```

It prompts me for the admin user name and password and then the page appears as shown below(Under the `Virtual Hosts` section):

[image]

```
Note: syed-virtualbox and localhost are both one and the same
```

As shown in the above image, i have added 2 new users usr1 and usr2.

Now inorder to test is my server is working, I am downloading the samples/examples of the Library Strophe.js from this url:

https://github.com/strophe/strophejs/archive/v1.2.14.tar.gz

The samples can be found under the `Examples` folder of the extracted Directory.
As shown below:

[image]

Now i edit all the js/javascript files in this directory and change the parameter BOSH_SERVICE to point to my localhost i.e. http://localhost:5280/xmpp-httpbind as shown in the below image:

[image]

Now, i start using the `basic.html` file in the browser and enter the JID as usr1 (As mentioned in [Unable to connect to ejabberd localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666092/unable-to-connect-to-ejabberd-localhost) )and its password. I get the below response:

[image]

Note: I get the same response even if i use usr1@localhost or usr1@syed-virtualbox

```
So i would like to know is there something that i'm doing wrong?
OR
Can someone provide me some working sample of Strophe on localhost?
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to connect?
I am getting net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your configuration file and see if tls is true or false under bosh configuration. If tls is true then please use HTTPS over HTTP when connecting to the bosh service URL.

Answer (score 1):

I guys, I am not sure if this is still relevant. I have `tls=true` in my ejabberd.yml settings, and I used

```
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'https://localhost:5280/xmpp-httpbind';
```

but I got the same errors.

What worked for me is:

```
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'wss://localhost:5280/websocket';
```